# Bootstrap grid: remove 'col col-xs-12' on the large screen?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I remove or over write `col col-xs-12` in an element when it is on a large screen **without** using js/ jquery? I just need `col col-xs-12` on the smaller screen.

mobile/ smaller screen,

```
<div class="col col-xs-12">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" class=""/>
</div>
```

While on the large screen,

```
<div class="col col-xs-12">
      <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" class=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't remove without js, but you can target its visibility on a large screen with `display:none;` with css media queries.

Comment: Check out the responsive utility classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Thanks all. how do I use media query to remove those classes?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the input to appear at all on large screen??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**#1 : you want the input to not appear on large devices :**

```
<div class="col col-xs-12 hidden-lg">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" class=""/>
</div>
```

**#2 : you want another width on large devices :**

```
<div class="col col-xs-12 col-lg-6"> <!-- change col-lg-6 as you want -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" class=""/>
</div>
```

**#3 : you want with:100% back on large devices (require a media query)**

```
<div class="col col-xs-12 autosize-lg">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" class=""/>
</div>
```

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .autosize-lg {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```